# 17.10: shutdown on power button, unity

Tags: power-management, shutdown, 17.10

I want to be able to init shutdown on my home theater pc by pressing the power button. (as I could on every other distro and older versions of ubuntu+tweak manager)

i could do that earlier with the silly step of installing tweak tools and enabling it there. but even that doesnt't list the shutdown option anymore. only suspend.

already tried adding  `HandlePowerKey=poweroff` to system.d/logind.conf which did nothing (i am reading on systemd, still clueless on it)

edit: if i login to unity instead of gnome, the power button shows the shutdown dialog (with lock, restart, shutdown options). but unity settings has zero options to control the power button action.